# Get Remain of Account in Accounting software

Tags: c#, sql, select

I have a problem

```
SELECT Tbl_ZAsnad.zs_id ,
       V_ALLAccounts.h_name ,
       zs_bed ,
       zs_bes ,
       (SELECT SUM(Tbl_ZAsnad.zs_bed) - SUM(Tbl_ZAsnad.zs_bes) FROM Tbl_ZAsnad
        WHERE k_code = 12 and m_code = 2 and t_code = 10 and zsid < "***GET Current value of zs_id***")
FROM Tbl_ZAsnad , V_ALLAccounts
WHERE k_code= kid
and m_code = mid 
and t_code = tid
and k_code = 12 and m_code = 2 and t_code = 10
```

I want to get current value of zs_id

Comment: Name outer Tbl_ZAsnad t1, and inner Tbl_ZAsnad  t2. Use t1.zs_id in the sub-select's condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify the outer Tbl_ZAsnad, now called t1:

```
SELECT t1.zs_id ,
       V_ALLAccounts.h_name ,
       zs_bed ,
       zs_bes ,
       (SELECT SUM(t2.zs_bed) - SUM(t2.zs_bes) FROM Tbl_ZAsnad t2
        WHERE k_code = 12 and m_code = 2 and t_code = 10 and zsid < t1.zs_id)
FROM Tbl_ZAsnad t1, V_ALLAccounts
WHERE k_code= kid
and m_code = mid 
and t_code = tid
and k_code = 12 and m_code = 2 and t_code = 10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
cmd = "INSERT INTO Tbl_FacBuy(fb_id , k_code , m_code , t_code , fb_date , fb_totalPrice , fb_type) "
                                + "VALUES(@a1,@a2,@a3,@a4,@a5,@a6,@a7)" + Environment.NewLine
                                + "INSERT INTO Tbl_ItemsSell(is_fid , is_storeid) "
                                + "VALUES(@a1,@a8)" + Environment.NewLine
                                // Save Sanad
                                + "INSERT INTO Tbl_Asnad(s_id,s_details,s_date,s_tbed,s_tbes, s_FactorID) "
                                + "VALUES(@s1,@s2,@a5,@a6,@a6,@a1)" + Environment.NewLine
                                + "INSERT INTO Tbl_ZAsnad(s_id,k_code,m_code,t_code,zs_details,zs_bed,zs_bes) "
                                + "VALUES(@s1,@a2,@a3,@a4,@s2,@a6,0)" + Environment.NewLine
                                + "INSERT INTO Tbl_ZAsnad(s_id,k_code,m_code,t_code,zs_details,zs_bed,zs_bes) "
                                + "VALUES(@s1,60,4,0,@s2,0,@a6)";
                            cmd_FSell.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a1", int.Parse(txt_FacId.Text.Trim()));
                            cmd_FSell.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a2", int.Parse(arr_acc[0].ToString().Trim()));
                            cmd_FSell.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a3", int.Parse(arr_acc[1].ToString().Trim()));
                            cmd_FSell.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a4", int.Parse(arr_acc[2].ToString().Trim()));
                            cmd_FSell.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a5", clspd.trimDate(clspd.persianDate(0)));
                            cmd_FSell.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a6", double.Parse(txt_Price.Text));
                            cmd_FSell.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a7", 2);
                            cmd_FSell.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a8", int.Parse(storeID));
                            cmd_FSell.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s1", int.Parse(s_id));
                            cmd_FSell.Parameters.AddWithValue("@s2", "فاکتور فروش شماره " + txt_FacId.Text);
```

///// Show this Message :

> String or binary data would be truncated.
>
> String or binary data would be truncated.
>
> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_Tbl_ZAsnad_Tbl_Asnad". The conflict occurred in database
>   "Autogallery_DB", table "dbo.Tbl_Asnad", column 's_id'.
>
> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_Tbl_ZAsnad_Tbl_Asnad". The conflict occurred in database
>   "Autogallery_DB", table "dbo.Tbl_Asnad", column 's_id'.
>
> The statement has been terminated.
>
> The statement has been terminated.
>
> The statement has been terminated.
>
> The statement has been terminated.